# Error when declaring and using a string

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-views

How can I reference a variable that I have created in a `MVC` `Razor` `View`?

I have declared a variable as follows:

```
@string bootstrapCSSPath = @Path.Combine(Model.pathToResourceDirectory, "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css");
```

Now I wish to use this variable in html.

Here is my code:

```
<link href="@bootstrapCSSPath" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

When the `View` is displayed, the following error is shown:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term 'string'

Comment: `@{string bootstrapCSSPath = Path.Combine(Model.pathToResourceDirectory, "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css");}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Razor you can declare variables or use c# code by using parantheeses {}, in your case:

```
@{
   string bootstrapCSSPath = @Path.Combine(Model.pathToResourceDirectory, "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css");
}
```

and

```
<link href=@Html.Raw(bootstrapCSSPath) rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

you can lool on [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/) blog for more information

Answer (score 0):

when declaring varibles in View it should enclosed in `{}`

```
@{string bootstrapCSSPath = 
           @Path.Combine(Model.pathToResourceDirectory, 
               "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css");
}
```

see my comment in your question